# Apply corner radius to only two corners for button in Swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui

Problem and Try

```
struct PlayGroundThirdView: View {

 //some variables
 //some vm and controller

  var body: some View {
    //some views

    Button {
        vcontroller.fetch()
        vcontroller.setColor(.red)
    } label: {
        Text("Refresh")

    }
    .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .leading)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .background(.red)
    .cornerRadius(20)
    
 }


}
```

I want corner radius of button only apply to TWO corners Only for leading direction but has never work with clipshape or even alignment leading.

What i actually want [image]

Comment: And what did you actually try? At least search?

Comment: hello again sir i tried corner leading part +     clipShape(Circle().frame(width: 50, alignment: .leading))

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved with working with just `padding()` for this case.

[image]

```
HStack {
  Spacer()
  Button("Refresh") {
  ...
  }
  .padding(10)
  .foregroundColor(.white)
  .background(.red)
  .padding(.trailing, 20) //corner radius part
  .cornerRadius(20) //corner radius part
  .padding(.trailing, -20) //corner radius part
}
```